Why is my no-underline not working in react
I'm using Tailwind CSS in my React project, and I'm having trouble removing the underline from NavLink components. I’m applying the no-underline class, but it's not removing the underline as expected.
 <NavLink
      to="/dashboard"
      className={`text-2xl hover:${isDarkMode ? 'text-yellow-400' : 'text-linkGray'} transition duration-300 no-underline`}
      activeClassName={`${isDarkMode ? 'text-yellow-400' : 'text-linkGray'}`}
    >
      <Home size={20} className="inline mr-2" />
      Home
    </NavLink>

I tried using inline styles, but I realized I want to do purely tailwind css\

use dev tools to see what is overriding the css class

it seems like nothings overriding it it's in react if that could be a problem tho it doesn't appear so

It's hard to guess without the source code, but I also bet that something is overriding no-underline; you can try to use the ! to make the rule "important" !no-underline

Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
